# Optimizing Conway's Game of Life for an Arduino

Tags: matrix, optimization, arduino, conways-game-of-life, arduino-c++

I am making Conway's Game of life on an Arduino with a 64x64 dot matrix grid. it is working but its a little slow while running the full size. This is the code that I think is taking the longest:

```cpp
int same;
int c;

// My code can run in different sizes so these needed to be writable.
int width1=64;
int height=64;

int row0[WIDTH]; // WIDTH is just the constant 64.

void check(int y)
{
  int alive=0;

  for(int x=0;x < width1;++x)
  {
    alive=0;
    if(x > 0)
    {
      if(getPixelColor(x-1, y) > 0)
      {
        alive+=1;
        //Serial.println("(left)");
      }
    
    }
    if(x < width1-1)
    {
      if(getPixelColor(x+1, y) > 0)
      {
        alive+=1;
        //Serial.println("(right)");
      }
    }
    if(y > 0)
    {
      if(getPixelColor(x, y-1) > 0)
      {
        alive+=1;
        //Serial.println("(top)");
      }

      if(x > 0)
      {
        if(getPixelColor(x-1, y-1) > 0)
        {
          alive+=1;
          //Serial.println("(top left)");
        }
      }
      if(x < width1-1)
      {
        if(getPixelColor(x+1, y-1) > 0)
        {
          alive+=1;
          //Serial.println("(top right)");
        }
      }
    }
    if(row < height-1)
    {
      if(getPixelColor(x, y+1) > 0)
      {
        alive+=1;
        //Serial.println("(bottom)");
      }

      if(x > 0)
      {
        if(getPixelColor(x-1, y+1) > 0)
        {
          alive+=1;
          //Serial.println("(bottom left)");
        }
      }

      if(x < width1-1)
      {
        if(getPixelColor(x+1, y+1) > 0)
        {
          alive+=1;
          //Serial.println("(bottom right)");
        }
      }
    }
    god_Conway(x, y, alive);
  }
}

void god_Conway(int x, int y, int a)
{
  int born[]={3};
  int survive[]={2, 3};
  int kill=0;
  bool birth1=0;
  int living=getPixelColor(x, y);

  if(living > 0)
  {
    if (a == 2 || a == 3)
    {
      kill=1;
    }
  else
  {
    kill=-1;
  }    
  }
  else
  {
    if (a == 3)
    {
      birth1=1;
    }
  }


  if (kill == -1 || birth1 == 1)
  {
    for(int c=0;c<width1;c++)
    {
      if(row0[c]==-1)
      {
        row0[c]=x;
        if(c,width1)
        {
          row0[c+1]=-1;
        }
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if(kill == 1 || birth1 == 0)
  {
    same++;
  }
}
```

This code checks around each pixel in a row and discovers how many pixels are on around a certain pixel. `getPixelColor(x, y)` is code I found for the matrix the reads the pixel's color and return a number greater than 0 if on. The check function takes about 29-30ms per row. Every millisecond counts.

I've tried a big if for just the non-edge pixels. `getPixelColor(x, y)` does not always return same number so dividing it by expected return number is not always accurate. I made a function to return 1 and 0 automatically then do `alive+=That_function(x, y);` but it slowed it down.

It only writes down the y of the pixels that needs changing on `row0`. The code that prints this stops when there is a -1.

Comment: first impression -- use consistent (x,y) or (row, column). You're mixing x and row and it's making it hard to read. I'm suggesting that you make that change right now. Making your question easier to read will attract higher quality answers and will attract them faster.

Comment: Your `check` function has `O(width^2)` complexity. You repeat this for each row (I assume), so each iteration is going to increase in complexity `O(N^3)` where `N = length of one side of the board`.

Comment: Tips to make this easier to read (for both you and any reviewers): (1) Don't use global variables except where absolutely necessary. That means only variables you need to persist between calls to `loop()`. At _worst_ that's probably only the 64x64 game board. (2) Use consistent indentation, (3) delete comments before sharing with people. That's one extra line I have to read over with my eyes. (4) `kill` and `birth` should probably be `bool`.

Comment: Slightly off-topic for C++, but you might consider assembly for this.  I wrote GOL on a Z80 a couple of years back, on a wraparound (toroidal) board... 64x64 it ran about 20 *generations* per second, not *rows*.  Many will scoff saying compilers are too good to beat these days, but it is possible.  Oh yeah, and that Z80 runs on a Veraboard computer of my own design, at 8.192MHz.

Comment: If your board can have different sizes (as mentioned in the first comment in your code), then dimensioning `row0` with the constant `WIDTH` is problematic.

Comment: What did you intend to do with `if(c,width1)` using the comma operator? Seems like it should be `if (c < with1 - 1)`? Your question is about speed, but it looks like you have bugs in your code.

Comment: you use `getPixelColor(x,y)`only to check for >0. Perhaps you change it to returning bool ? [ e.g. `if (getPixel(x,y)) ...` ]

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the time consuming function `getPixelColor` to read the pixels from the display. Instead maintain the board in memory, e. g. `static char board[64][64];`, and keep a copy of the previous generation also in memory. If there is no library function to display the whole image at once, you need at least to call the presumed `setPixelColor` function only for the changed pixels.
You might even use a `static char board[66][66];` with the image indexes 1..64 and spare yourself the edge considerations.

Comment: two static char board[64][64] are pretty big for "real" Arduinos. What about one bit per pixel only?

Comment: Yes, one bit per pixel is surely more efficient regarding memory, though maybe not with regard to runtime.

Comment: I tried this but as soon as I have a `bool grid[64][64]` and wright even a single thing to it, the dot matrix goes crazy. Even the the compiler says the program uses 52% of the memory for an arduino mega. It runs into and issue

Comment: Chances are, this undisclosed program has a bug.